# Doing a telnet from heroku bash

Tags: heroku, telnet, heroku-toolbelt

I want to check if a server is accessible from my heroku server. I tried getting bash and then running telnet command but getting message

> bash: telent: command not found

Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Unless it's a typo, you've mis-spelled telnet in the error message above.  Secondly, `telnet` is terribly insecure and probably not allowed by heroku.  you might try `ssh` instead.  would `ping` be enough to tell if your remote server is accessible from heroku?

Comment: Thaks mr rogers, yes that was a type. I checked it later also telnet is allowed from heroku and i was in need of it because i need to check if machine accessible for a specific port.